# Can we Convert Anonymous Type to List <T> using Linq to entity in C#?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have a table with three columns i want to use self join and retrieve the columns with alias name.

Table:`Material(ID,Name,MaterialParentID)`

```
public List<Material> GetMaterialList()
{
    List<Material> materilaList = new List<Material>();
    var query = (from c1 in db.Materials
                 join c2 in db.Materials on c1.ID equals c2.MaterialParentID
                 select c2);        

    return query.ToList();
}
```

I want to add following to exisiting query and return the List

```
select new { c2.ID, c2.MaterialParentID, c2.Name, ParentName = c1.Name })
```

Comment: return this `query.Select(c2=> new { c2.ID, c2.MaterialParentID, c2.Name, ParentName = c1.Name }).ToList()`

Comment: @wudzik: That wouldn't work. `List<anonymous type>` is not the same as `List<Material>`.

Comment: hello @wudzik query contains only c2 fields and so getting error at ParentName=c1.Name any idea?

Answer (score 6):

Just use the actual concrete type instead of an anonymous one:

```
select new Material { 
    ID = c2.ID, 
    MaterialParentID = c2.MaterialParentID, 
    Name = c2.Name,
    ParentName = c1.Name 
}
```

Comment: you can't use a model's entity in a select clause in linq to entities (so you'd have to do this after the `ToList()`)

Comment: i have replaced select c2 with your code it says:Invalid intialize member declarator!

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE - try updated code. Basically you just need to create instance of your `Material` class. You might want to call the constructor directly. I don't have the source code for your class..

Comment: But when i am using the c1.Name it shows error again. since we have c2. Actually i wan to display the ID,Name,MaterialParentID & ParentName=c2.Name get parent & child with names and id too...? I have show the table fields too!

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE - does your `Material` class, which you're returning from the `GetMaterialList()` method contain a property `ParentName`? You might want to declare a new class that will hold all the data you want to return.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33619/discussion-between-shekhar-shete-and-jakub-konecki)

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach(var row in query)
{
    material mat =new material();
    mat.id=row.ID;
    mat.name=row.Name;

    materilaList.add(mat);
}

return materiList;
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, could you please explain it?